# Win32 AccessCheck does not give expected result

Tags: windows, winapi, acl

I'm trying to understand why I'm not getting the expected result from [`AccessCheck`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-accesscheck) function.

Given the following scenario:

- The currently logged-in user is running a process.
- The user is a member of the `Administrators`, `Authenticated Users` and `Users`.
- There is a folder at `C:\Test`. `Users` only has `Read & Execute` & `List folder Contents` and `Read` permissions. `Authenticated Users` has `Modify` permissions. `Administrators` has full control.
- The process has a restricted token where the `Administrators` is set with the `SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY` flag, which indicates that the access ACLs are not considered at all.
- Executing the `AccessCheck` will indicate that the current user only has the `Read & Execute` & `List folder contents`, `Read` and `Write` but not `Modify` permissions.
- However, if the process executes the equivalent of `mkdir` and `rmdir` on the `C:\Temp` and create a new folder `C:\Temp\Test`, it will succeed. Because the delete is a part of the `Modify` permission, the `rmdir` equivalent should have failed.

It's important to note that the token still designates the `Administrators` as a deny-only group even if it's the unrestricted primary token (presumably because the process is run as a normal user without any elevation). I am assuming that the `AccessCheck` stopped evaluating the access with `Administrators` and did not check the ACLs for `Authenticated Users` or `Users`, but it doesn't explain why the `mkdir` would succeed even though `AccessCheck` reports no `Write` permission available.

It may be also helpful to note that the user can perform the same action interactively via the explorer and is able to do so without doing any admin escalation, even though the user does not have `Write` permission via the `Users` membership but rather via either `Administrators` or `Authenticated Users` membership.

Using the MCRE given below, the following output is given:

```
AccessCheck: 1
Access mask: 1701bf
  FILE_ALL_ACCESS: 0
  FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE: 1
  FILE_GENERIC_READ: 1
  FILE_GENERIC_WRITE: 1

60      Mandatory Label\Medium Mandatory Level
7       \Everyone
10      BUILTIN\Administrators
7       BUILTIN\Performance Log Users
7       BUILTIN\Users
7       NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
7       \CONSOLE LOGON
7       NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
<omitted additional groups>

Created directory at C:\Temp\Test
Deleted directory at C:\Temp\Test
```

Based on the output of `AccessCheck`, the deletion of the directory should not have happened, yet it did. Why?

How do we get `AccessCheck` to report that the user has in fact the ability to create and delete a directory in this scenario?

Here is a MCRE (not worrying about error checking or memory leaks):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <wtypes.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <aclapi.h>
#include <securitybaseapi.h>
#include <sddl.h>

int main()
{
    std::ostream hexcout(std::cout.rdbuf());
    hexcout << std::hex;

    DWORD result;
    PSID pOwner;
    PSID pGroup;
    PACL pDacl;
    PACL pSacl;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    HANDLE hPrimaryToken;
    HANDLE hImpersonationToken;
    PRIVILEGE_SET ps{};
    DWORD psl = sizeof(ps);
    GENERIC_MAPPING gm{};
    gm.GenericAll = FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE | FILE_GENERIC_READ | FILE_GENERIC_WRITE;
    gm.GenericExecute = FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE;
    gm.GenericRead = FILE_GENERIC_READ;
    gm.GenericWrite = FILE_GENERIC_WRITE;
    
    ACCESS_MASK ga = 0;
    BOOL as = 0;
    LPCWSTR path = L"C:\\Temp";
    
    result = GetNamedSecurityInfoW(path, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION, &pOwner, &pGroup, &pDacl, &pSacl, &pSD);
    hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    result = OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hPrimaryToken);
    result = ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hPrimaryToken);
    result = DuplicateTokenEx(hPrimaryToken, 0, NULL, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL::SecurityDelegation, TOKEN_TYPE::TokenImpersonation, &hImpersonationToken);
    result = AccessCheck(pSD, hImpersonationToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, &gm, &ps, &psl, &ga, &as);
    
    std::cout << "AccessCheck: ";
    hexcout << result << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Access mask: ";
    hexcout << ga << std::endl;

    std::cout << "  FILE_ALL_ACCESS: " << ((ga & FILE_ALL_ACCESS) == FILE_ALL_ACCESS) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE: " << ((ga & FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE) == FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  FILE_GENERIC_READ: " << ((ga & FILE_GENERIC_READ) == FILE_GENERIC_READ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  FILE_GENERIC_WRITE: " << ((ga & FILE_GENERIC_WRITE) == FILE_GENERIC_WRITE) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    DWORD l = 0;

    result = GetTokenInformation(hImpersonationToken, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS::TokenGroups, NULL, 0, &l);

    PVOID ptr = GlobalAlloc(GPTR, l);
    result = GetTokenInformation(hImpersonationToken, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS::TokenGroups, ptr, l, &l);
    PTOKEN_GROUPS tg = (PTOKEN_GROUPS)ptr;

    DWORD c = tg->GroupCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        DWORD NameLength = 255;
        DWORD DomainLength = 255;
        SID_NAME_USE sUse = SidTypeUser;
        
        LPWSTR Name = (LPWSTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, NameLength * sizeof(WCHAR));
        LPWSTR Domain = (LPWSTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, DomainLength * sizeof(WCHAR));
        DWORD Attributes = tg->Groups[i].Attributes;

        result = LookupAccountSidW(NULL, tg->Groups[i].Sid, Name, &NameLength, Domain, &DomainLength, &sUse);
        
        hexcout << Attributes;
        std::wcout << "\t" << Domain << "\\" << Name << std::endl;

        GlobalFree(Name);
        GlobalFree(Domain);
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    result = CreateDirectoryW(L"C:\\Temp\\Test", NULL);
    if (result)
    {
        std::cout << "Created directory at C:\\Temp\\Test" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create directory: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    result = RemoveDirectoryW(L"C:\\Temp\\Test");
    if (result)
    {
        std::cout << "Deleted directory at C:\\Temp\\Test" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to delete directory: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] showing how you are calling `AccessCheck()`? Don't just provide a *description* of what the code does.

Comment: *Authenticated Users* usually have almost all permissions on folder, except `FILE_DELETE_CHILD`. i guess that this group have `FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY` permission on folder

Comment: Updated the question to include the MCRE. I hope that helps.

Comment: simply show *Advanced Permissions* for *Authenticated Users* from explorer. like this - https://i.imgur.com/Brwxd3o.png . *I am assuming that the AccessCheck stopped evaluating the access with Administrators and did not check the ACLs for Authenticated Users* - wrong

Comment: I see the same thing you show in the linked screenshot but therefore the code should not have been able to delete the subfolder it just created. Considering that the result of `AccessCheck` reported that the user did not have the `FILE_ALL_RIGHTS` which includes the ability to delete subfolders & files. Yet `RemoveDirectoryW` succeeds anyway. Why?

Comment: but need only `DELETE` access for delete. and *Authenticated Users* have it (in my screenshot)

Comment: You need to check [Standard Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/standard-access-rights) instead of [Generic Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/generic-access-rights) which cannot imply the `DELETE` right. Also see [Access Mask Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-mask-format). As far as Access Mask `1701bf` which is `00010111 0000000110111111` in binary is concerned, DELETE(0x00010000L), READ_CONTROL(0x00020000L) and WRITE_DAC(0x00040000L) are allowed!

Comment: This is the crux of my confusion. My mistake was that I read [the table on MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-security-and-access-rights) which does not list the `DELETE` at all. It is indicated in the paragraphs above the table, but the table includes other standard rights, giving the impression that `DELETE` wasn't used. Therefore, this is a reading failure on my part for focusing on the table and not the entire article. I think the other part that is confusing is that there is no such thing as `FILE_GENERIC_MODIFY` to correspond to `Modify` on dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76335892/win32-accesscheck-does-not-give-expected-result#comment134685086_76335892) in the comment, you need to check [Standard Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/standard-access-rights) instead of [Generic Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/generic-access-rights) which cannot imply the DELETE right. Also see [Access Mask Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-mask-format). As far as Access Mask `1701bf` which is `00010111 0000000110111111` in binary is concerned, `DELETE(0x00010000L)`, `READ_CONTROL(0x00020000L)` and `WRITE_DAC(0x00040000L)` are allowed!